# Upload files to s3 bucket using boto3: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using boto3 for uploading files to s3 bucket

Here is the code I am using

```py
# s3 client initialization
s3_client = boto3.client(
    service_name='s3',
    region_name='us-west-2',
    aws_access_key_id=access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
    #endpoint_url='https://s3:us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    verify=True
)
```

If `Verify = TRUE`, then I am getting this error:

> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)

If `Verify = False`, then I am getting this error:

> InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'itd-us-west-2-**-****-*****.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#tls-warnings
> warnings.warn(

Just wanted to check here if I am doing any mistake?

**UPDATE:** I am getting Unverified HTTPs request is being made to host but the files get copied:

```py
def upload_files_to_s3_CLI(files, s3location, s3_folder):
  for file_data in files:
    file_location = file_data['FileLocation']
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_location)
    command = f"aws s3 cp {file_location} s3://{s3location}/{s3_folder} --no-verify-ssl subprocess.run(command, shell=True, check=True)
```

Comment: Why are you calling the AWS CLI from Python in that second code example? There should be no need to do this. What happens  if you do not specify `Verify` at all in the first code example -- which error appears? That is the problem to solve, rather than trying to turn off verification.

Answer (score 0):

- There's a typo in the hostname. Should be a period, not a colon.
- Make sure you can run that command with those credentials from the AWS CLI.
- Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: I was able to upload using CLI cp command in python. here is the code for it. I am getting Unverified HTTPs request is being made to host but the files get copied. 
```
def upload_files_to_s3_CLI(files, s3location, s3_folder):
    for file_data in files :
        file_location = file_data['FileLocation']
        file_name = os.path.basename(file_location)
        command = f"aws s3 cp {file_location} s3://{s3location}/{s3_folder} --no-verify-ssl
        subprocess.run(command, shell=True, check=True)
```
I commented the endpoint url which has colon you are referring